# Go get on golang docker image results in segmentation fault

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to run a Go web app in a docker image. When installing dependencies via **RUN go get**, I get a segmentation fault. When installing dependencies and running **go build** locally, I'm able to compile correctly.

I have tried using glide and dep to vendor my dependencies, but I am not sure if dependency management is the issue here. I am also unsure why when using the `-v` flag in `go get -v`, the last dependency being installed is `github.com/user/hftl/app`, which is the directory that I'm copying all my `.go` files to in the container.

I'm using Docker For Mac.

**Output of running docker build ./**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  11.78MB
Step 1/9 : FROM golang:1.10
 ---> 1c1309ff8e0d
Step 2/9 : ARG app_env
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4a9c7610a671
Step 3/9 : ENV APP_ENV $app_env
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 577846d489df
Step 4/9 : COPY ./app /go/src/github.com/user/hftl/app
 ---> 4a531e5ed4c1
Step 5/9 : WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/user/hftl/app
Removing intermediate container 5b21fc994dba
 ---> 878133804037
Step 6/9 : RUN go get -v
 ---> Running in a8ba8b45ffcc
github.com/gin-gonic/gin (download)
github.com/gin-contrib/sse (download)
github.com/golang/protobuf (download)
github.com/ugorji/go (download)
Fetching https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8"} at https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8?go-get=1
gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8 (download)
Fetching https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "gopkg.in/yaml.v2": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"gopkg.in/yaml.v2", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2"} at https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1
gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (download)
github.com/mattn/go-isatty (download)
github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig (download)
github.com/lib/pq (download)
github.com/lib/pq/oid
github.com/gin-gonic/gin/json
github.com/gin-contrib/sse
github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8
github.com/ugorji/go/codec
gopkg.in/yaml.v2
github.com/mattn/go-isatty
github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig
github.com/lib/pq
github.com/gin-gonic/gin/render
github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding
github.com/gin-gonic/gin
github.com/user/hftl/app
go tool link: signal: segmentation fault
The command '/bin/sh -c go get -v' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM golang:1.10

ARG app_env

# assign app_env variable from build -> APP_ENV in container shell
# can either be dev or production: set in docker-compose.yml under 'web'
ENV APP_ENV $app_env

# copy app directory to container
COPY ./app /go/src/github.com/user/hftl/app

# all container commands run from this path
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/user/hftl/app

# install go deps and build binary
RUN go get -v
RUN go build

# start the server
# hot-reload via pilu/fresh on save of a Go file
CMD if [ ${APP_ENV} = production ]; then \
        app; \
        else \
        go get github.com/pilu/fresh && \
        fresh; \
        fi

EXPOSE 8080
```

[EDIT 1]:

I changed the `FROM golang:1.10` to `FROM golang:1.9.4` at the top of my Dockerfile and it seems to have resolved the issue, so it must be a problem with the official go 1.10 image. If anyone could clarify why `go tool link` would produce a segmentation fault on 1.10, but not 1.9.4, that would be wonderful.

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Corrected, sorry - first post on S.O.

Comment: @JustinYeh on your local machine is the `./app` folder also located under `$GOPATH/src/github.com/user/hftl/`?

Comment: @mkopriva the full path of `./app` is `~/go/src/github.com/jyyeh77/hftl/` but I thought it wouldn't matter if I just copied the contents of `./app` via `COPY ./app /go/src/github.com/user/hftl` in the Dockerfile and set the working directory as such. Or does it matter?

Comment: This could be due to some corruption of the 1.9 image. You could try deleting the `golang:1.9` image and then rebuilding...

Comment: @JustinYeh I think, I'm not sure, it would matter if you have sub packages under `./app`, say `./app/foo`, and your application is importing them. Let's say in `./app/main.go` if you have an import like `"github.com/jyyeh77/hftl/app/foo"`, but on docker it's located under `"github.com/user/hftl/app/foo"` then that could cause a problem I believe, but I'm not sure if a linker segfault would be the result of this. And since you were able to resolve it by changing the version to 1.9 it means that you either don't have subpackages that you import or that it actually isn't a problem at all?

Comment: @mkopriva great point, I eventually made sure that my import paths in `./app` matched up with the directory structure created on docker - I think this was completely unrelated to the seemingly corrupted golang 1.10 image i was using.